# Backup database in SQL Server 2008 (Compatibility Level 90) restore to 2005

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, backup, restore

I have a database I was given by a client from a SQL Server 2005. When I restored it on my SQL Server 2008 R2 I made sure the compatibility level was set to 90.

Now I need to back it up and give it back to them and they get the dreaded malformed headers error.

I know I've done this before but cannot remember what needs to be done to allow it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, I guess it can't be done and has nothing to do with compatibility levels.

I will use a script.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that's exactly the answer - it cannot be done. You cannot ever go "back" in terms of versions of SQL Server - backup files from a newer version cannot be restored on earlier versions - regardless of the compatibility level.

Comment: It's funny how I distinctly remembered doing it before. Ha. And I thought the compatibility level made SQL Server treat the database as a 2005 database. But it doesn't do that at all. All it does is apply the 2005 versioned syntax.